# How to query database for rows from next 5 days

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I make a query in SQL Server to query for all rows for the next 5 days.
The problem is that it has to be days with records, so the next 5 days, might become something like, Today, Tomorrow, some day in next month, etc...

Basically I want to query the database for the records for the next non empty X days.

The table has a column called Date, which is what I want to filter.

Comment: Please show sample data with expected results.

Comment: what's the criteria for "days with records"? is there another table where you have date and data against the date? Or same table has multiple columns along with "date"?

Comment: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

Why not split the search into 2 queries.  First one searches for the date part, the second uses that result to search for records IN the dates returned by the first query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select date from table where date  in  (select distinct top 5  date 
from table where date >= getdate() order by date)
```

Comment: This will not include today, tomorrow,... This will select top 5 dates that are more than 5 days from today. You need to change condition to `where date >= getdate()` and `order by date` not `order by date desc'

Answer (score 0):

@Anagha is close, just a little modification and it is OK.

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE DATE IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT TOP 5 DATE
        FROM TABLE
        WHERE DATE >= referenceDate
        ORDER BY DATE
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following SQL query where 5 different dates are fetched at first then all rows for those selected dates are displayed

```
declare @n int = 5;
select *
from myData 
where 
    datecol in (
    SELECT distinct top (@n) cast(datecol as date) as datecol
    FROM myData
    WHERE datecol >= '20180101'
    ORDER BY datecol
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your values are dates, you can use `dense_rank():

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, dense_rank() over (order by datecol) as seqnum
      from t
      where datecol >= cast(getdate() as date)
     ) t
where seqnum <= 5;
```

If the column has a time component and you still want to define days by midnight-to-midnight (as suggested by the question), just convert to `date`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             dense_rank() over (order by cast(datetimecol as date)) as seqnum
      from t
      where datetimecol >= cast(getdate() as date)
     ) t
where seqnum <= 5;
```